# Python Asyncio HTTP Server won't server requests concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I do not understand how the Python built-in asyncio http server works ([asyncio.start_server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server)). I would expect that the server is able to handle several concurrenet requests. However, that does not seem to be the case.

I took the example from the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#tcp-echo-server-using-streams) and adapted it slightly:

```
import asyncio


async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    print("Enter echo handler")
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info("peername")

    print("Enter my long running task")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("Finished my long running task")

    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    writer.close()
    print("Exit echo handler")


async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, "127.0.0.1", 8888)

    addrs = ", ".join(str(sock.getsockname()) for sock in server.sockets)
    print(f"Serving on {addrs}")

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


asyncio.run(main())
```

I start that programm and send via my webbrowser two requests at the same time in two different browser tabs.

That is the output on the terminal:

```
Enter echo handler
Enter my long running task
Finished my long running task
Exit echo handler
Enter echo handler
Enter my long running task
Finished my long running task
Exit echo handler
Enter echo handler
Enter my long running task
Finished my long running task
Exit echo handler
Enter echo handler
Enter my long running task
Finished my long running task
Exit echo handler
```

It is clearly visible that the requests are handled sequential. I would expect that I'm able to accept a request, work on a task and return the results and that for several tasks in parallel.

Can someone explain / clarify how to achieve what I want and / or explain why the tasks are not executed in parallel. It seems that something is blocking the event loop.

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce. If I run the code you have posted, then open 2 different terminals and run 2 different `telnet localhost 8888` commands, I'm able to write in both and I see `Enter echo handler -> Enter echo handler -> Enter my long running task -> Enter my long running task` etc. Maybe you are using a single connection to test this and you expect that every line you type should start a new request?

Comment: I just tried it with `curl localhost:8888` and I do get the same output as you. So it seems to work as expected with `telnet`/ `curl` but not with requests from my webbrowser.

Comment: Do not use web browsers to make these tests.. Webbrowser are highly optimized. They can reuse the connections, or maybe they notice that you are opening the same url in multiple tabs and that it is not loading and so they wait before performing a new request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Apparently, it is somehow related to the webbrowser. However, I'm still surprised that the webbrowser seems to send the requests in a sequence. The right number of requests hits my Python webserver, just in a sequential order.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you try to use different web browsers it will work:  open both Chrome & Firefox, and open the url in both. You'll see 2 concurrent requests. Browser are extremely complicated and they are highly optimized for their use case. If a browser knows that a website is blocking, it will avoid sending other requests to that website since it knows that chances are really high that all those requests will get stuck. To verify simple things use simple tools that do not have a lot of hidden behaviours.